# Which driver do I have installed?

Tags: ati, graphics

I have installed AMD flgrx-updates from Ubuntu repos. Which version driver is it? On the AMD website the latest AMD Catalyst driver is 12.10 stable and 12.11 Beta.

Answer (score 0):

"Using Ubuntu-supplied fglrx/Catalyst on Ubuntu Quantal, will install fglrx/Catalyst 9.000, which is roughly equivalent to Catalyst 12-9" [[from this guide]](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide#Using_Ubuntu-supplied_fglrx.2FCatalyst) The page also gives instructions for downloading the current drivers from AMD's web site.